# A characterization of nuclear functionals in terms of continuity with respect to some special topologies on $B(X)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I think, nuclear functionals on the space of operators $B(X)$ (on a Banach space $X$) must have a characterization in terms of some special continuity. I would be grateful if somebody could help me with the following hypothesis.

First, a *nuclear functional* on $B(X)$ (where $X$ is a Banach space) is a linear functional $u:B(X)\to{\mathbb C}$ that can be represented in the form
$$
u(A)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda_n\cdot f_n(Ax_n),\qquad A\in B(X),
$$
where $\lambda_n\in{\mathbb C}$, $x_n\in X$, $f_n\in X^*$ are such that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda_n|<\infty,\quad \sup_{n}||x_n||\le 1,\quad 
\sup_{n}||f_n||\le 1.
$$
Let us denote by $B_{pc}(X)$ the space $B(X)$ of operators $A:X\to X$ endowed with the *topology of pointwise convergence* (in the case when $X$ is a Hilbert space it is usually called the *strong operator topology*).

Note that a set of operators $T\subseteq B_{pc}(X)$ is totally bounded in $B_{pc}(X)$ iff for each $x\in X$ the set $\{Ax;\ A\in T\}$ is totally bounded in $X$.

And note that each nuclear functional $u:B(X)\to{\mathbb C}$ is continuous on each totally bounded set $T\subseteq B_{pc}(X)$ with respect to the topology induced from $B_{pc}(X)$ (since $T$ is bounded with respect to the norm in $B(X)$ by the Banach-Steinhauss theorem, and using this we can "cut off the tail of the series up to arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$").

It seems to me, this can be turned back:

> **Conjecture:** a linear functional $u:B(X)\to{\mathbb C}$ is nuclear if and only if it is continuous on each totally bounded set $T\subseteq B_{pc}(X)$ with respect to the topology induced from $B_{pc}(X)$.

This is true when $X$ is a Hilbert space. Is it true for arbitrary Banach space $X$? At least for $X$ with the approximation property?

Of course, we can assume in addition that $u$ is contunuous on $B(X)$ with respect to the usual norm topology, since this follows from the continuity of $u$ on each totally bounded set $T\subseteq B_{pc}(X)$.

Comment: Your conjecture is correct. This is covered in volume one of Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri. Tricky things happen when X fails the approximation property (one must distinguish nuclear operators from nuclear tensors), but that is also treated in Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri. X has the  AP if and only if trace is well defined for nuclear operators. That is, if X fails the AP, then there is a nuclear representation of the zero operator for which the trace of the representation can be anything.

Comment: @BillJohnson could you, please, give a more precise reference? Which statement in Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri do you mean?

Comment: Proposition 1.e.3 in "J. Lindenstrauss and L. Tzafriri, Classical Banach Spaces, I, Springer Verlag, Classics in Mathematics, 1996." I think is what you want.

Comment: @MeisamSoleimaniMalekan why if a functional $\varphi$ is continuous on compact sets of $L(X,Y)$ then it is continuous on $L(X,Y)$ (where $L(X,Y)$ is endowed with the compact-open topology)?